# Laravel Automatic resource CRUD

Tags: laravel, eloquent, orm, crud, repository-pattern

What patterns can I use for 'automatic' resource CRUD operations for given Models in Laravel?

---

Say I have two models `SomeModel` and `SomeRelatedModel` where `some_related_model.some_model_id` is an FK to `SomeModel`.

The standard method on the `SomeModelController` for handling the create `POST /api/someModel` might look like this:

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $user = Auth::guard('api')->user();

    $data = $request->get('data');
    $data['user_id'] = $user->id;

    $someModel = SomeModel::create($data);

    // has this request been made with the data for the
    // related model? If so create this too.
    if($data['relatedModel']){
        SomeRelatedModel::create(array_merge(
          ['some_model_id' => $someModel->id]
          $data['relatedModel']
        ));
    }

    // has this request been made expecting to get related
    // models back in the response? If so load these
    if($request->has('with')){
        $someModel->load($request->get('with'));
    }

    return (new PostResource($post))
        ->toResponse($request)
        ->setStatusCode(201);
}
```

This works but is very verbose and for models with a sub-sub relation would need changing further. Similar work will need to be done for the other endpoints for all resources.

Is there a more versatile (or tidy) pattern using out-of-the box classes to get a similar effect?

Comment: Maybe not what you want to hear, but passing the entire request data into the create function - including the data for the related models is just asking for trouble.

Comment: If you have created SomeModel (as $someModel) then I would use that to create the related model like `$someModel->someRelatedModel()->create($request->only(['list','of','related','fields']))` instead of array merge

Comment: The models all have `$fillable`s. Probably I'd replace the standard Request with a FormRequest to define the allowed inputs anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Laravel Orion](https://tailflow.github.io/laravel-orion-docs/). Fits your use case.

Comment: This looks like it might be a good shout. Do you happen to know if it will get upset with related models that are actually the same table row?

For legacy reasons we have tables hundreds of columns wide, with many columns like `relatedthing_columnname` which we have seprate models for, but use the same table name and 'id' as their 'parent' table